# How to set case insensitive to Set<String>

Tags: java, collections

```
Set<String> h = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b", "A"));
```

It will set "a", "b", "A".

But, I want to do case-insensitive.

So, it will give "a", "b"

In, DTO request

```
public class EmpDto{
    private String empName;
    private Set<String> roles;
}
```

Like, If I want to get in sort order

```
    private Set<String> roles;
```

Is there any predefined implementation or custom implementation required?
If custom, give me a head start

Comment: There is no inbuilt method...Seems u have to take distinct of the list in lower case .. list.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    Set<String> h = Stream.of("a", "b", "b", "A")
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: That is ok. But, I am expecting that DTO from request

Comment: Means, in DTO I can only write Set declaration

Comment: this one? Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b", "A")

Comment: Set<String> str = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

Comment: This one worked